# CSS Flex hard breaking items

Tags: css, razor, flexbox

I tried to hard break flex items of 36 days into 12 left justified items per row  without any success.  Currently all 36 items are displayed on one row. Here is my ASP.NET CORE .cshtm.  Thank you.

```css
flex-start {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  display:flex;
  flex: 1 0 21%; 
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-start">
  @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfClosingDates)
  {
    DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(item.OriginalDate.YearID, item.OriginalDate.MonthID, item.OriginalDate.StopEnteringDataAfter);
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="@thisDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")" type="text" value="@thisDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='@thisDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")' class='@((item.Updatable == true) ? "icon swingable" : "icon")' data-editable="@((item.Updatable == true) ? "true" : "false")">
      <strong class="time-header">@thisDate.ToString("MMM"), @thisDate.Year</strong>
      <span class="time-body">@thisDate.Day</span>
      <em class="time-footer">@thisDate.DayOfWeek</em>
    </time>
    @if (item.Updatable)
    {
      <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='@thisDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")'>Adjust Closing Date</a>
    }
  </div>
  }
</div>
```

This is rendered in IE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>List - Indicator Admin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uswds/2.6.0/css/uswds.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/loadAwesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/calendar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/indicator.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">
          <img src="/images/_logo.png" alt="Indicator Admin" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="appTitle"><em>Indicator Admin</em></div>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
          
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/AzureAD/Account/SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
</ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Admin</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="spinnerContainer">
    <div class="la-ball-spin-clockwise-fade-rotating la-3x">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
      <div style="padding-top:150px">
        

<h1><span class="text-shadow">FY2019~FY2021 Closing Dates for Data Submission</span></h1>


<aside>
  <h3>
    <a class="btn refresh" href="/">Refresh</a>
  </h3>
</aside>

<div class="msgContainer btn-shadow absoluteCenterContainer">
  <div class="spaceBetweenFlex">
    <span id="msg" class="popupMessageArea"></span>
    <div class="closeButton">&#x22A0;</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-start">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-08-2021" type="text" value="12-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='12-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-08-2021" type="text" value="11-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='11-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2021" type="text" value="10-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='10-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-09-2021" type="text" value="09-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='09-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-09-2021" type="text" value="08-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='08-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2021" type="text" value="07-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='07-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-08-2021" type="text" value="06-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='06-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-10-2021" type="text" value="05-10-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-10-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='05-10-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2021" type="text" value="04-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='04-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-08-2021" type="text" value="03-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='03-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-08-2021" type="text" value="02-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='02-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-11-2021" type="text" value="01-11-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-11-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">11</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='01-11-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-08-2020" type="text" value="12-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='12-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-09-2020" type="text" value="11-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='11-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2020" type="text" value="10-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='10-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-09-2020" type="text" value="09-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='09-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-10-2020" type="text" value="08-10-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-10-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='08-10-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2020" type="text" value="07-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='07-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-08-2020" type="text" value="06-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='06-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-08-2020" type="text" value="05-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='05-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2020" type="text" value="04-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-vssc btn-shadow" href="/Admin/TransferToBI">BI Transfer</a>  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-09-2020" type="text" value="03-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-09-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-10-2020" type="text" value="02-10-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-10-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-09-2020" type="text" value="01-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-09-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-09-2019" type="text" value="12-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-08-2019" type="text" value="11-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2019" type="text" value="10-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-10-2019" type="text" value="09-10-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-10-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-08-2019" type="text" value="08-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2019" type="text" value="07-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-10-2019" type="text" value="06-10-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-10-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-08-2019" type="text" value="05-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2019" type="text" value="04-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-08-2019" type="text" value="03-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-08-2019" type="text" value="02-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-09-2019" type="text" value="01-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
</div>


      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

  <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
      &copy; 2020 - IndicatorAdmin - <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".spinnerContainer").hide();
    $('.msgContainer').click(function () { $(this).hide() });

    $('.closingDate').css('display', 'none').filter(function () {
      return Date.parse($(this).data('closingdate')) >= new Date();
    })
    .focus(function (e) {
      $('.closingDate').datepicker("destroy");
      $('.closingDate').datepicker({dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"});
      $('.closingDate').datepicker("option", "dateFormat" );
      console.log('closing date input click');
      console.log('calendar default date', $(this).data('closingdate'));
      $('.closingDate').datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date($(this).data('closingdate')),
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        stepMonths: 0
      });
    });

    $(".editable").click(function (e) {
      $('.closingDate').filter(function () {
        return Date.parse($(this).data("closingdate")) >= new Date();
      }).css('display', 'block');
      editDate($(this), e)
    });

    $('#createDates').click(function(e){createDates(e)});

    $("time").filter(function () {
      return Date.parse($(this).attr("datetime")) <= new Date();
    }).click(function (e) {
      //alert('Old date cannot be changed');
      $('#msg').html($(this).attr("datetime") + ' is an older date and cannot be changed');
      $('.msgContainer').removeClass('success').addClass('failure').show();
    });

    $("time").filter(function () {
      return Date.parse($(this).attr("datetime")) >= new Date();
    }).css('display', 'block').click(function (e) { editDate($(this), e) });


    function editDate(objThis, e)
    {
      console.log('e', e);

      var $this = objThis;
      console.log('$this', $this);

      var thisDate;
      var thisNewDate = new Date(1);

      if ($this[0].tagName == 'TIME') {
        thisDate = new Date($this.attr("datetime"));
        console.log('from <time> element> ', thisDate);
      }
      else {
        thisDate = new Date($this.data('closingdate'));
        console.log('from .editable class', thisDate);
      }

      e.preventDefault();

      $('#msg').html('');
      $(".spinnerContainer").show();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/EditByAjax',
        //data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        data: {
          NewDate: { YearID: thisNewDate.getFullYear(), MonthID: thisNewDate.getMonth()+1, StopEnteringDataAfter: thisNewDate.getDate() },
          OriginalDate: { YearID: thisDate.getFullYear(), MonthID: thisDate.getMonth()+1, StopEnteringDataAfter: thisDate.getDate() },
          Updatable: true,
          InitiateTransferToBI: true
        },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true
      })
      .then(function (returnData) {
        console.log(returnData.message);
        $('#msg').html(returnData.message);
        if (returnData.message.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf("failure") === -1) {
          console.log('pass1');
          $('.msgContainer').removeClass('failure').addClass("success").show();
        }
        else {
          console.log('pass2');
          $('.msgContainer').removeClass('success').addClass("failure").show();
        }
        $(".spinnerContainer").hide();
      })
      .fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log('pass3');
        $('#msg').html(err.message);
        $('.msgContainer').removeClass('success').addClass("failure").show();

        $(".spinnerContainer").hide();
      });
    };

    function createDates(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#msg').html('');
      $(".spinnerContainer").show();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/CreateByAjax',
        //data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        type: "GET",
        async: true
      })
      .then(function (returnData) {
        console.log(returnData.message);
        $('#msg').html(returnData.message);
        if (returnData.message.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf("failure") === -1) {
          console.log('create date pass1');
          $('.msgContainer').removeClass('failure').addClass("success").show();
        }
        else {
          console.log('create date pass2');
          $('.msgContainer').removeClass('success').addClass("failure").show();
        }
        $(".spinnerContainer").hide();
      })
      .fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log('create date pass3');
        $('#msg').html(err.message);
        $('.msgContainer').removeClass('success').addClass("failure").show();

        $(".spinnerContainer").hide();
      });
    }
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide simple html of it?

Comment: please see the attached image.  Thanks.

Comment: Please don't provide code in image, please make snippet in codepen and give us so we can simply find problem and solve it

Comment: Thanks.  Please see the rendered code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, 12 items per row:

```css
.flex-start {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 calc(100% / 12 - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-start">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-08-2021" type="text" value="12-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='12-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-08-2021" type="text" value="11-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='11-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2021" type="text" value="10-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='10-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-09-2021" type="text" value="09-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='09-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-09-2021" type="text" value="08-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='08-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2021" type="text" value="07-09-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='07-09-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-08-2021" type="text" value="06-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='06-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-10-2021" type="text" value="05-10-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-10-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='05-10-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2021" type="text" value="04-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='04-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-08-2021" type="text" value="03-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='03-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-08-2021" type="text" value="02-08-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-08-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='02-08-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-11-2021" type="text" value="01-11-2021" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-11-2021' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2021</strong>
      <span class="time-body">11</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='01-11-2021' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-08-2020" type="text" value="12-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='12-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-09-2020" type="text" value="11-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='11-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2020" type="text" value="10-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='10-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-09-2020" type="text" value="09-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='09-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-10-2020" type="text" value="08-10-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-10-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='08-10-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2020" type="text" value="07-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='07-09-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-08-2020" type="text" value="06-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='06-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-08-2020" type="text" value="05-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-08-2020' class='icon swingable' data-editable="true">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-vssc btn-shadow editable" data-closingdate='05-08-2020' href="/Admin/Edit">Adjust Closing Date</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2020" type="text" value="04-08-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-vssc btn-shadow" href="/Admin/TransferToBI">BI Transfer</a> </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-09-2020" type="text" value="03-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-09-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-10-2020" type="text" value="02-10-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-10-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-09-2020" type="text" value="01-09-2020" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-09-2020' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2020</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="12-09-2019" type="text" value="12-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='12-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Dec, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="11-08-2019" type="text" value="11-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='11-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Nov, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="10-08-2019" type="text" value="10-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='10-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Oct, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="09-10-2019" type="text" value="09-10-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='09-10-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Sep, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="08-08-2019" type="text" value="08-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='08-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Aug, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Thursday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="07-09-2019" type="text" value="07-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='07-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jul, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Tuesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="06-10-2019" type="text" value="06-10-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='06-10-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jun, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">10</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="05-08-2019" type="text" value="05-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='05-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">May, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="04-08-2019" type="text" value="04-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='04-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Apr, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Monday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="03-08-2019" type="text" value="03-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='03-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Mar, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="02-08-2019" type="text" value="02-08-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='02-08-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Feb, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">8</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Friday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div>
      <input class="closingDate btn-shadow" data-closingdate="01-09-2019" type="text" value="01-09-2019" />
    </div>
    <time datetime='01-09-2019' class='icon' data-editable="false">
      <strong class="time-header">Jan, 2019</strong>
      <span class="time-body">9</span>
      <em class="time-footer">Wednesday</em>
    </time>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user266909, when I run the code in my answer I see 3 rows, 12 items per row.